# Reset Bootstrap modal when clicking outside modal window

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm having some problems with reseting my bootstrap modal whenever the user clicks outside the modal window to dismiss instead of pressing the dismiss button. My datetimepicker stops working whenever the modal window doesnt reset properly.

This is what my modal should do whenever it opens:

[image: Image1]

But this is what happens if I open the window just after dismissing my window by hitting the gray area outside the modal window:

[image: Image2]

Whenever I dismiss using the `Avbryt` (dismiss) button it works just fine. 
I get no errors and this is the code I use for my modal

```
$scope.show = function() {
    ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: 'newProject.html',
            controller: "NewProjectModalController"
        }).then(function(modal) {
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function(result) {
                $('#newProjectModal').modal('hide');
                $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            }
        });
    });
}
$scope.dismiss = function () {
    close(false, 500)
}
```

The modal service can be found on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4v1mcsg/).

I discovered that its not really the backdrop that is triggering the dismiss but the edges of the modal window. If I hit the outside of the modal within the small square, its dismisses, but not if I hit the backdrop outside.

[image]

Comment: Mind showing the code for `ModalService`?

Comment: Too few code here. If the answer below doens't work, please post more code. (definition of `close` for example)

Comment: @Pytth Added the code for ModalService. Also added a small update to the question. I also noticed that clicking outside the modal window does not delete the previous window, while the dismiss button does. This is probably why the calendar fails, because of multiple ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the image in question, you are using *angular-modal-service* along with bootstrap.js  in your project. So I searched its github repo and found this issue: https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/issues/107

According to the comments there, you should change your code as below:

```
ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: 'newProject.html',
        controller: "NewProjectModalController"
    }).then(function(modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function(result) {
            $('#newProjectModal').modal('hide');
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        }
        // added by me
        modal.element.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {// bootstrap event
            modal.scope.close(false,500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for finding a similar issue, I've tried for ages. However I get `Uncaught TypeError: modal.scope.close is not a function`, any idea? UPDATE: Nevermind, problem solved, just entered the modal scope identifier, which was probably what you ment. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry that the code doesn't work, but I have tried it in the angular-modal-service's offical jsfiddle. It may be caused by the difference between your code and it. @PhyCoMath

Comment: See updated comment :) It worked, just had to change the scope :)

Comment: Fine :D @PhyCoMath

Answer (score 2):

Try triggering a click event on the Avbryt button when a user clicks on the modal backdrop. Something like this:

```
$('.modal-backdrop').click(function(){
  $('.avbryt').trigger('click');
});
```

That should bypass whatever the underlying problem is.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I updated my question as I noticed something with your code. The modal dismiss is actually being triggered by a click OUTSIDE of the modal window but inside the modal class, and not by the backdrop click. I also noticed that clicking outside the modal window doesnt delete the previous window, only hides it. But the dismiss button deletes it.